# How to use "use" from inside a method?

Tags: php

I have the following code that works fine

```php
require_once realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/../../vendor/autoload.php');
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
$reader = new Reader('/var/lib/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
[...]

class geoIP {
    function __construct($ip) {
        global $reader;
        $record = $reader->city($ip);
    }
}
```

I want to move the complete namespace GeoIp2 inside the class Foo but it won't let me use `use` inside the class. How could I do this?

Comment: You can not put a namespace into a class. What is your goal? BTW: There's a bunch of unusual code here, so I would strongly recommend submitting the working code to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "I want to move the complete namespace GeoIp2 inside the class Foo" - why do you want that? Which problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: "use" statements are not executable code, they don't have scope; they are just a way to say "in this file, when I write 'Reader', I actually mean '\GeoIp2\Database\Reader'"

Comment: @NicoHaase to make the class portable in a file and add it to other projects.

Comment: @IMSoP is this per included or required file or per complete site?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this class more "portable" when the `use` statements are moved to any other place where they don't belong?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can not share more details. But you can try this link https://duckduckgo.com/?q=portable&ia=definition

Answer (score 4):

As the PHP manual [states](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope), the `use` keyword must be outside of blocks / function definitions / etc.

> The `use` keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

If you don't want to use the `use` keyword, use fully qualified names: `new GeoIP2\Database\Reader('/var/...')`

Comment: I am going to do the second one. Use the fully qualified  names and drop the use ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use your constructor to create the object. You should not use global variables in OOP code when possible.

You can add a protected member variable `$reader`, for instance:

```php
<?php

use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
[...]

class geoIP {
    protected $reader;

    function __construct($ip) {
        $this->reader = new Reader('/var/lib/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
        $record = $this->reader->city($ip);
    }
}
```

Also:

- Are you sure you need to require all of `vendor/autoload.php`? This should not be needed.
- Should your class have a namespace as well?

Comment: > Are you sure you need to require all of vendor/autoload.php
- yes because GeoIP2 is in the vendor folder outside the webspace.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Your comment about vendor/autoload.php suggests you're not familiar with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) or with [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) in general. If so, I strongly recommend learning about both.

Comment: Oh so you don't use a framework then. I just never not used a framework with composer.